# Margin right does not work when in div that is overflowed

Tags: overflow, margin

How to add margin right to this overflowed div (or table). All other margins are fine except right one. Thank you. Table should be 100% width. If I remove that margin right is not visible again. Margin right is visible only if parent div is large enough.

[JsFiddle demo](http://http%20://jsfiddle.net/bigorns/4cwdq04v/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-right: 10px` in your TABLE (not div)

[JsFiddle Answer](https://jsfiddle.net/4cwdq04v/1/)

Comment: I need a space between border and scrollbar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately if you replace 200px with 10px then it does not work.